# Finding pattern of unkown size

Tags: machine-learning, prediction

Is it possible to find a pattern of unknown size e.g.

12**3**12 24**3**12 -> A

12412 24**3**12     -> B

12**3**412 24112    -> B

What I am looking for is a method to predict the pattern of class A which means by combining both sequence changes of position 3 in both sequences of class B, results in class A instead of class B.

The size of the pattern is unknown. Is it possible to find a pattern (not class label) with machine learning or deep learning?

Comment: It’s impossible to do inference without assumptions. What do you believe is the structure of the pattern? (Just looking at 3 examples, I have no idea what I’m looking at. What pattern are you talking about?) If you have a large number of examples of A and B, you may be able to learn the relationship.

Comment: Its about single-nucleotide polymorphism in genetics.  I do have a large number of examples for A and B and the sequence lengths is large ( several thousands).  The idea is to find a combination of changes as pattern which leads to a specific phenotype ( A=blue eyes, B=green eyes).

Comment: If this is learnable at all, it’s only going to be for the simplest relationships between sequence and phenotype. There’s going to be _a lot_ of noise in this process.

Comment: Which NN / machine learning methods type would you recommend? I find only methods to predict the phenotypes but not the pattern.

Comment: The main problem is that the size of the pattern is unknown,  it could be 2 or 200. So it should be something with combinatorics.

Comment: Well, that’s probably less of an issue than you think. (You have the same problem in language processing.) It’s not as if the patterns are completely random. There has to be _some_ consistency in order for the biological mechanism to make sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229295/discussion-between-honeymoon-and-arya-mccarthy).